# How does a Tkinter checkbox control corresponding textbox widget? Python

Tags: python, tkinter, text, checkbox, widget

I have a simple tkinter program, where upon clicking a "Create boxes" button, it creates a Checkbutton and a Text widget. I was trying to enable/disable the Text widget based on the Checkbutton. eg- if the Checkbutton is ticked the corresponding Text button will be disabled.

And the following code does work as desired, but I have no idea how?
How does a Checkbutton keep track of the corresponding Text widget?

I have tried it with multiple Checkbuttons and they all don't *seem* to interfere with the other's Text widgets.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x300')

def create_boxes():

    def disable_text():
        if textbox['state'] == NORMAL:
            textbox['state'] = DISABLED
        else:
            textbox['state'] = NORMAL


    checkbox = Checkbutton(root, command = disable_text)
    textbox = Text(root, height= 1, width = 30)

    checkbox.pack()
    textbox.pack()

create_chechkbutton = Button(root, text= 'Create a checkbox and textbox', command= create_boxes)
create_chechkbutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Any explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkbox itself is actually not keeping track of anything. What this code does is **binds** the checkbox to the `disable_text()` function. In effect, this means that `disable_text()` is called whenever the checkbox is  checked. So, it is actually the *function* `disable_text()` that is keeping track of the text.

When the checkbox is created: `checkbox = Checkbutton(root, command = disable_text)`, the `disable_text()` function is passed to the `command` argument. This tells tkinter to call `disable_text()` whenever the checkbutton is pressed.

In `disable_text()`, there is an `if` statement that checks if the text is disabled. If the text is *disabled*, `disable_text()` *enables* it. If the text is *not* disabled, then `disable_text()` *disables* it.

Note that this does not get the state of the checkbox; that is, it does not set the state of the text based on the state of the checkbox: it sets the state of the text based on the state of the text. So, if the text were to *start out* disabled instead of enabled, the checkbox would be checked when the text was enabled, and unchecked when it wasn't. You could make `checkbox` a `Button` instead of a `Checkbutton`, and it wouldn't make a difference how the code was run.

If there were multiple checkbuttons in your program, each with their own text, the `disable_text()` function would have to be bound using the `lambda` statement, with an argument telling it which checkbutton was calling it. Here is an example of multiple checkbuttons controlling multiple text widgets:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x300')

def create_boxes():

    def disable_text(checkbox): ### EDITED LINE
        textbox = checkbox.textbox ### ADDED LINE
        if textbox['state'] == NORMAL:
            textbox['state'] = DISABLED
        else:
            textbox['state'] = NORMAL

    for x in range(0, 5): ### ADDED LINE
        checkbox = Checkbutton(root)
        checkbox.config(command=lambda checkbutton=checkbox: disable_text(checkbutton)) ### EDTIED LINE
        textbox = Text(root, height= 1, width = 30)
        checkbox.textbox = textbox ### ADDED LINE

        checkbox.pack()
        textbox.pack()

create_chechkbutton = Button(root, text= 'Create a checkbox and textbox', command=create_boxes)
create_chechkbutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Using a `for` loop, the checkbuttons and text widgets are created and packed. `checkbox.textbox = textbox` creates a new attribute of `checkbox`, and assigns it to the checkbox, so that that checkbox is associated with that text widget. The line

```py
checkbox.config(command=lambda checkbutton=checkbox: disable_text(checkbutton))
```

enables the checkbutton to pass itself as an argument to `disable_text()` when it calls it. Then, `disable_text()` simply gets the text widget associated with the checkbutton it got in its argument, and disables or enables it.

Comment: So, in case of multiple Checkbuttons, how does the *one* ```disable_text``` function distinguish between which Text widget instance to disable/enable? Or does every checkbutton has a ``` disable_text ``` function instance bounded to it, which keeps track of *its* Text widget (which may be the last one created, upon calling the function) ?

Comment: @Ye_kya: It would ideally be _one_ `disable_text()` that can identify which text it must change, based on the checkbutton that called it. I will put this in my answer; I think I misunderstood that part of your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer in such detail and for code expalanation. It has much more clarity and I can see how that works. I would consider my attempt a ridiculous hacky way to *seemingly* achieve the same results, but I myself wouldn't trust it.